# References on the theory of Petrov-Galerkin methods for more "basic" problems

Tags: finite-element, reference-request

In my reading on various aspects of FEM, Petrov-Galerkin methods often arise in the study of solutions of convection-dominated systems, such as Hughes' work on Navier-Stokes, or systems where optimal test spaces or test bases are desirable, for example, some of the discontinuous PG work of Demkowicz, and least-squares PG in reduced-order modeling. However, in almost every textbook-level treatment of the subject, PG methods are at most a single mention when introducing the concept of test and trial spaces and the entirety of the text is dedicated to Galerkin methods.

My question is, are there any good references that develop the theory of PG methods for more "basic" problems or in a more comprehensive manner, akin to how the theory for Galerkin methods are generally presented? I suppose it isn't surprising that there are fewer book-level resources on it given its later development and the effectiveness of Galerkin methods on symmetric problems, which are easier to teach. Even something much older with a heavier functional analysis lean would satisfy me (although I can't read Russian), as I am now just curious on where and how the basic theoretical developments of PG were performed. I thought about asking Math SE, but figured the knowledge base in this forum would be better suited. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Actually, there is not much literature about this topic. However, to give a useful comment, Petrov-Galerkin methods can simply be thought as a non-orthogonal projection as soon as the approximation comes into play. You may also think of it as a orthogonal projection in basis (A) a priori represented in a different basis (B).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I believe I already have a pretty good conceptual understanding of PG from bits I've gathered (different test space leads to non-symmetric problems, equivalent to non-orthogonal projections, most FD and FV methods can be rewritten as PG), but I guess I just always found it a bit unsatisfying intellectually. For example, how exactly does the choice of test basis impact convergence for, e.g., Poisson eq? Advection eq? Compared to vanilla Galerkin? I'm willing to believe the literature is very sparse on this

Comment: Well nothing stops you from solving a simple Poissons eq with different test functions (a sort of pointless trivial PG i guess). I remember an old course I took which started off by solving a simple 1D ODE by hand, choosing a 3 trial and 3 test functions and just integrating it (a good exercise to try i think). The reason why vanilla Galerkin chooses test = trial is well documented i think, and you'd only reach for PG when you have to for some other reason, like stability.

Comment: I had the same exercise in my first FEM class haha. I'm not really concerned with the practical applications, as they seems to be relatively niche. I am more interested on if anybody anywhere has gone through a lot of error estimates and related theorems for PG on problems for which they were not explicitly formulated for (e.g., advection)